# C# calling C++ dll attempts to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, c++, exception, visual-studio-2012, dll

I am trying to use a function drom a DLL, but I keep getting an `XamlParseException`, but I am able to see while running step by step my program that I get an `AccessViolationException`, which I think is the cause of the first exception.
Basically, what the function is supposed to do is to log me to a directory of a program to use the different classes to interact with the program.
I do not have access to the source of the DLL, but I have some documentation to use it, even though there aren't a lot of information in it, here is how I am supposed to use it :

```
    Logon(BSTR DirectoryPath, BSTR ErrorFile, int Lang)
```

And here is my code :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    private delegate int Logon([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]String DirectoryPath, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]String ErrorFile, int Lang);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        try
        {

            string LnkPsbEppPath = "dll/LnkPsbEpp.dll";
            IntPtr pAddressFctLogon = GetProcAddress(LnkPsbEppLink, "@Tdtm_Dossier@Logon$qv"); 
            if (pAddressFctLogon == IntPtr.Zero)
                Console.WriteLine("Logon function not found");
            else
            {   
                try
                {
                    dynamic logon = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pAddressFctLogon, typeof(Logon));
                    dynamic varLogon = logon(directoryPath, errorFilePath, 2); // <-- Here is where the AccessViolactionException happend
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR : " + ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, in the documentation that comes with this DLL, it is specified that if you're using `Logon`, it will automatically try to connect to the SQL Server if it's not done yet. May this be the reason of the `AccessViolationException` ?

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? And would you mind sharing your knowledge with the world (or al least me)? I'm actually having the exact same issues as you are. I'm basically trying to achieve the exact same thing... Expert/M is such a pain

Answer (score 0):

Check that C++ dll whether it provides you the permission to write .

Check C++ dll documentation for more details

Even I faced same problem when I was using C++ dll in my WPF application

Answer (score 0):

It could happen if in unmanaged code, there is some Null pointer being accessed.